# Update Table based on minimal date within group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table schema representing some players and the teams that they play for:

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYERS
(
  NAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
  BIRTHDAY TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
  TEAM VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
  CAPTAIN BOOLEAN
);
```

My data looks like this

```
"PLAYER1","1998-02-13 00:00:00","TEAM_A",NULL
"PLAYER2","1984-01-13 00:00:00","TEAM_A","1" 
"PLAYER3","1985-07-13 00:00:00","TEAM_A",NULL
"PLAYER4","1979-08-13 00:00:00","TEAM_B",NULL
"PLAYER5","1986-09-13 00:00:00","TEAM_B",NULL
"PLAYER6","1990-11-13 00:00:00","TEAM_B",NULL
"PLAYER7","1993-12-13 00:00:00","TEAM_C",NULL
"PLAYER8","1987-05-13 00:00:00","TEAM_C",NULL
"PLAYER9","1995-04-13 00:00:00","TEAM_C",NULL
```

Now I have the requirement that each team needs exactly one captain. TEAM_A already has one (PLAYER2) but for TEAM_B and TEAM_C doesn't. So I need a SQl script, which identifies the oldest players within one team and sets the captain flag for them. Can anybody please help me on this.

Comment: the data doesn't correspond to the schema defined

Comment: Which database you are using

Comment: What flavor of SQL? Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: I am using mySQl here

Comment: @vkp I exportet the data from the DB (via CSV export)

Comment: @ghost bring that answer back i will fix it seriously

Comment: @DrewPierce undeleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by getting the oldest player for each team without a captain like this:

```
SELECT team, MIN(birthday) AS minBirthday
FROM myTable
WHERE team NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT team FROM myTable WHERE captain = 1)
GROUP BY team;
```

Once you have that, you can use it to update the captains using a JOIN:

```
UPDATE myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT team, MIN(birthday) AS minBirthday
  FROM myTable
  WHERE team NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT team FROM myTable WHERE captain = 1)
  GROUP BY team) t ON t.team = m.team AND t.minBirthday = m.birthday
SET m.captain = 1;
```

As it is written, this will set two captains if two players share the same minimum birthday. If you have another tiebreaker, you can adjust the inner query to pick the correct player, and adjust the join if necessary. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22f93/1) example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
UPDATE players p1 
SET    captain = 1 
WHERE  birthday = (SELECT Min(birthday) 
                   FROM   players p2 
                   WHERE  p1.team = p2.team) 
AND CAPTAIN <> 1
```

Comment: This fails if two people have the same birthday on a team

Comment: @Ghost - yeah exactly but there is no other column present to do the order.

Comment: If two persons have same B'day then first clarify it to whom captaincy has to be given :) then the same logic shall be converted in the sql query :)

Comment: @Fireblade his answer is absolutely correct. give him full marks.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to no longer be SQL Server code and learned some MySQL for the first time.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f132a/1/0)

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYERS
(
  NAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
  BIRTHDAY DATETIME NOT NULL, 
  TEAM VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
  CAPTAIN BIT
);

INSERT INTO PLAYERS (BIRTHDAY,CAPTAIN,TEAM,NAME) SELECT '1998-02-13 00:00:00',NULL,'TEAM_A','PLAYER1';
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (BIRTHDAY,CAPTAIN,TEAM,NAME) SELECT '1984-01-13 00:00:00',1,'TEAM_A','PLAYER2';
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (BIRTHDAY,CAPTAIN,TEAM,NAME) SELECT '1985-07-13 00:00:00',NULL,'TEAM_A','PLAYER3';
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (BIRTHDAY,CAPTAIN,TEAM,NAME) SELECT '1979-08-13 00:00:00',NULL,'TEAM_B','PLAYER4';
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (BIRTHDAY,CAPTAIN,TEAM,NAME) SELECT '1986-09-13 00:00:00',NULL,'TEAM_B','PLAYER5';
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (BIRTHDAY,CAPTAIN,TEAM,NAME) SELECT '1990-11-13 00:00:00',NULL,'TEAM_B','PLAYER6';
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (BIRTHDAY,CAPTAIN,TEAM,NAME) SELECT '1993-12-13 00:00:00',NULL,'TEAM_C','PLAYER7';
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (BIRTHDAY,CAPTAIN,TEAM,NAME) SELECT '1987-05-13 00:00:00',NULL,'TEAM_C','PLAYER8';
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (BIRTHDAY,CAPTAIN,TEAM,NAME) SELECT '1995-04-13 00:00:00',NULL,'TEAM_C','PLAYER9';

set @rownum=0;
SET @TEAM_names:='';

UPDATE Players p
JOIN(
  SELECT
     @rownum:=CASE WHEN @TEAM_names=TEAM THEN @rownum+1 ELSE 1 END as Row,
     @TEAM_names:=TEAM AS TEAM,
     name,birthday,captain
  FROM Players
  ORDER BY TEAM,BIRTHDAY
) ord on ord.NAME=p.name
    AND ord.BIRTHDAY=p.BIRTHDAY
    AND ord.TEAM=p.team
SET p.Captain= CASE WHEN Row=1 THEN true ELSE false END

SELECT *
FROM PLAYERS
ORDER BY TEAM,BIRTHDAY;
```

Comment: Do you think `mysql` has `row_number`

Comment: I just saw the added comment regarding SQL flavor.

Comment: hold on i will embed something

Comment: @DrewPierce Thanks, that led me in the right direction for researching and correcting my answer. I've never used MySQL and had the post been flagged as such, I never would have answered in the first place.

Comment: i like the inner part (ord) !  It works no matter how I slime the data

Comment: Any chance the down-voters can atleast remove their downvote?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this UPDATE statement to find captain:

```
UPDATE PLAYERS
SET
  CAPTAIN = 1
WHERE
  BIRTHDAY = (select min(BIRTHDAY) from PLAYERS where PLAYERS.TEAM = TEAM group by TEAM)
```